# Cannot connect to PostgreSQL database from Spring Boot application - FATAL: database does not exist

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I just configured new project with https://start.spring.io/
My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tower</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>tower</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tower

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=XXX


spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false
```

I got an error `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "tower" does not exist`. It says that my database is not up but I can easily get into it with pgAdmin3/4 and runs queries. I also use localhost:5432 with database name tower, user postgres and my password which is correct for sure. Why then I got and error that my database is not up.
I also tried:

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection connection = null;
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tower","postgres", "XXX");
```

and got exactly the same error- database "tower" does not exists.
Why I got such an error when database is up?

Comment: Do you have multiple installation of Postgres an running ?, There is possibility that you may connected to different DB.

Comment: VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.6.8, no other versions of postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on logging, at least you will see if you're trying to connect in Postgesql. Also try without using PGAdmin, like using the Squirrel SQL client which, unlike PGAdmin, will require you to set up the connection exactly how you describe ie URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tower 
If Squirrel connects then it's more like your code than PGAdmin

Comment: Yes, I had to set connection as in application.properties and found bug by this - name wasn't /tower. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but what worked for me is creating the db tower